# Message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver' : file not foundnSQLSTATE: 01000

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, odbc

I wanted to create a odbc connection using c++ with mysql and I have attached my code.
please help me rectify the error which is the title of the question I've posted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>

using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle) {
    SQLCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLCHAR message[1024];
    if(SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle,
           1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        cout<<"Message: "<<message<<"SQLSTATE: "<<sqlstate<<endl;
}

int main() {
    SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;    
    SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle;
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle,
           SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0)) 
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
    switch(SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle, NULL, 
                (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};PORT=3306;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=market;UID=root;PWD=123;", 
                SQL_NTS, 
                retconstring, 
                1024, 
                NULL,
                SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)){
     case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
          show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
          break;
     case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
     case SQL_ERROR:
          show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
          goto FINISHED;
     default:
          break;
    }

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, 
           sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
        goto FINISHED;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS!=SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle
           SQLCHAR*)"select * from employee", SQL_NTS)) {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
        goto FINISHED;
    }
    else{
        char name[64];
        char dept[64];

        while(SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle)==SQL_SUCCESS){
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, name, 64, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, dept, 64, NULL);
            cout<<" "<<name<<" "<<dept<<endl;
        }
    }

    FINISHED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle );
    SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);

}
```

Comment: Actually, now I see that it is your connection string... you need to replace `{MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}` with the location of the MySQL driver (as a DLL or shared library).

Comment: jsantander, no you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The Driver attribute in your call to SQLDriverConnect is "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver" so you should have an entry in your odbcinst.ini file like this:

```
[MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver]
driver = /some/path/to/libxxx.so
```

You need to check /some/path/to/libxxx.so exists, is readable, executable and lastly probably run ldd on it to ensure anything it depends on is already installed.

You can find your odbcinst.ini file with the command odbcinst -j .

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you do all the steps listed below.

1) Run ldd on driver's so file to check that all required libraries are loaded. If you find that it is not able to find some libraries, please add the path of those libraries manually in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

2) Create odbcinst.ini file if it does not already exist and add below entry

```
[MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = <Path_to_Dir_where_you_have_installed_driver>/libxxx.so
Setup           = <Path_to_Dir_where_you_have_installed_driver>/libxxx.so
```

3) Set environment variable ODBCINST to point to the just created odbcinst.ini.
   for e.g. if you are using bash shell, you can set the variable like below

```
export ODBCINST=<path_to_dir_where_odbcinst.ini_is_craeted>/odbcinst.ini
```

You can change the command accordingly depending on the shell you are using.

4) Setting ODBCINST only does not suffice in some cases and you need to set ODBCSYSINI to make sure that it is picking up the odbcinst.ini file you have set ODBCINST to in previous step.

```
export ODBCSYSINI=<path_to_dir_where_odbcinst.ini_is_created>
```

Again change the command based on the shell you are using.